# How can I catch fish consistently?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I'm doing the Kitty Catering mission and I'm trying to catch fish. I've gotten the "A fish is eyeing your lure!" message a few times and I've tried to "entice it" by changing the speed I reel in my line. However, I can't seem to entice the fish enough to catch anything.

My understanding of "changing reeling speeds" is holding down R2 for different lengths of time and moving the L stick back and forth. Is this not right? What am I supposed to do?

**Note**: I've since caught a few fish and finished the quest, but I still do not understand how to catch fish *consistently*. They inexplicably lose interest some times, but go straight for the bait other times, despite me not changing how I'm attempting to catch them. Is there a trick to this?

Comment: I think it's somewhat random. Sometimes I cast onto the fish and it bites without me doing anything. Sometimes moving the lure a bit and then letting it sit attracts their attention. Sometimes reeling in really fast does the trick. It's possible it varies by the fish type or even fish individual, which would make sense. Also keep in mind that different fish are attracted to different lures, so try changing the lure if they are consistently ignoring it. The fish there were quite quick to bite for me. I probably should have posted this as an answer.

Comment: @Kat hey thanks! This is pretty much what I've experienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience with fishing in FFXV the way you entice the fish is by doing short bursts of reeling in while moving the lure from left to right to get it moving. Once the fish bites make sure you get the QTE to hook the fish so you can start the reeling in process.

After you enter the reeling in phase slowly start to reel in the fish if you start to see the red and white flashing bar **stop reeling** in order to keep your line from snapping. If the bar tells you to move your left stick to the left or right make sure you do as such since it builds tension **a lot** if you fail to move your line. Also be sure to pay attention if the fish decides to jump in the water since it will prompt you for another QTE to keep the fish on the line. Repeat until you catch that fish!

And make sure you feed that cat!